# How can I update data on Firebase, Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

In sign up part I created the user like this:

```
**_authService
                          .createPerson(      //for sign up
                              _userNameTextController.text,
                              _userSurnameTextController.text,
                              _emailTextController.text,
                              _passwordTextController.text,
                              birth,
                              dropdownValue,
                              _addressTextController.text)
                          .then((value)**
```

but I can't update the data of the user. I tried to update like that:

```
 firestoreInstance.collection("Person").doc(userData.uid).update({
                          
                              "userName"  : _userNameTextController.text,
                              "userSurname" :_userSurnameTextController.text,
                              "country" : _addressTextController.text, 
                              "birth"   :birth,
                              "gender" :dropdownValue
                      
                       }).then((value)
```

What should i do?

Comment: Please share what error are you getting.

Comment: ı'm not getting an error It just doesn't update in Firebase

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you trying to add a new field 'country'. You can add a new field using `set()` with merge true.

```
firestoreInstance.collection("Person").doc(userData.uid).set({
    "userName"  : _userNameTextController.text,
    "userSurname" :_userSurnameTextController.text,
    "country" : _addressTextController.text, 
    "birth"   :birth,
    "gender" :dropdownValue,
  }
}, SetOptions(merge: true))
```